# Blazor button click event wire up

Tags: blazor

I have a fairly simple setup based on the standard Blazor template. I've done a fair amount of googling and I'm at a loss on how to properly architect this. I understand in general parameters flow down to decendants and events flow back up to the parents. I've got the CascadingValue sending params into the Index.razor page just fine, but I'm failing to understand how to wire up a button (click) within a custom component (FilterMenu) to a method on the Index.razor page when it's buried in the MainLayout @Body tag?

**Edit 1: This is for WebAssembly.**

Please help me understand!

My setup is as follows:

--FilterMenu.razor--

```
<div class="filterMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <button class="btn-success" @onclick="ApplyFilters">Do Work</button>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnClick_ApplyFilters { get; set; }

     private async Task ApplyFilters()
    {
        var filters = new FilterObject() { SomeFilter = "SomeValue"};

        ////TODO: This needs to flow through to the @Body (index.razor page) where we'll get the data and display for that page/component - But How!?

    }
}
```

--MainLayout.razor--

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <FilterMenu OnClick_ApplyFilters="ApplyFilters"></FilterMenu>
        </div>
        <CascadingValue Name="FilterValues" Value="@filters">
            <div class="content px-4">
                @Body
            </div>
        </CascadingValue>
    </div>
</div>
```

--Index.razor--

```
@page "/"

<div class="mainContent">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div>
                    Sample Data Grid here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div>
                    Sample Data 2 Grid here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "FilterValues")]
    protected Filters filters { get; set; }

    public async Task GetGridData()
    {
        //TODO: How to get this to execute from the button click in the FilterMenu component!?

        await LoadSampleData(filters);
        await LoadSampleData2(filters);
    }

    private async Task LoadSampleData(Filters filters)
    {
    //GetData
    }

    private async Task LoadSampleData2(Filters filters)
    {
    //GetData
    }
```

Comment: Is this blazor webassembly or server-side.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might change based on whether you're doing WebAssembly or Server-Side but the advice you're looking for (architect) is similar.

You could have a state that is shared across the application and inside of `Index.razor` you'll inject it and then set this shared state's event callback. Example below should get you started.

```
// Register to your DI container.
// FilterMenuState.cs
public class FilterMenuState
{
    public EventCallback<string> OnClick_ApplyFilters { get; set; }
}
```

```
// MainLayout.razor
@inject FilterMenuState FilterMenuState

<FilterMenu OnClick_ApplyFilters="FilterMenuState.OnClick_ApplyFilters" />
```

```
// Index.razor
@inject FilterMenuState FilterMenuState;

// Body...

@code 
{
    private void OnInitialized()
    {
        FilterMenuState.OnClick_ApplyFilters += DoThings;
    }
    
    private string DoThings() { }
    
    // Dispose...
}
```

No changes needed to `FilterMenu.razor`. Don't forget to dispose/set null on `FilterMenuState.cs` as cleanup.

Comment: Many thanks for the guidance. I'm running into issues however -Attribute 'Inject' not valid on declaration type. I think I see the pattern here, but I'm still not sure how to correctly wire this up. Is there a sample project somewhere that showcases this perhaps?

Comment: I have no example I can share besides the above (which I can confirm works on Blazor Server Side). Let me fix my examples as I accidentally mixed code-behind syntax with razor file syntax...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now on the Index page I'm getting Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'EventCallback' and 'Task' - any thoughts?